# PHP SMPP delivery report deliver_sm_resp not receiving?

Tags: php

```
    <?php
/*

File : smppclass.php
Implements : SMPPClass()
Description : This class can send messages via the SMPP protocol. Also supports unicode and multi-part messages.
License : GNU Lesser Genercal Public License: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/lgpl.html
Commercial advertisement: Contact info@chimit.nl for SMS connectivity and more elaborate SMPP libraries in PHP and other languages.

*/

/*

The following are the SMPP PDU types that we are using in this class.
Apart from the following 5 PDU types, there are a lot of SMPP directives
that are not implemented in this version.

*/
/*
define(CM_BIND_TRANSMITTER, 0x00000002);
define(CM_SUBMIT_SM, 0x00000004);
define(CM_SUBMIT_MULTI, 0x00000021);
define(CM_UNBIND, 0x00000006);
define(CM_ENQUIRELINK, 0x00000015);
*/

define('generic_nack', 0x80000000);
define('bind_receiver', 0x00000001);
define('bind_receiver_resp', 0x80000001);
define('bind_transmitter', 0x00000002);
define('bind_transmitter_resp', 0x80000002);
define('query_sm', 0x00000003);
define('query_sm_resp', 0x80000003);
define('submit_sm', 0x00000004);
define('submit_sm_resp', 0x80000004);
define('deliver_sm', 0x00000005);
define('deliver_sm_resp', 0x80000005);
define('unbind', 0x00000006);
define('unbind_resp', 0x80000006);
define('replace_sm', 0x00000007);
define('replace_sm_resp', 0x80000007);
define('cancel_sm', 0x00000008);
define('cancel_sm_resp', 0x80000008);
define('bind_transceiver', 0x00000009);
define('bind_transceiver_resp', 0x80000009);
define('outbind', 0x0000000B);
define('enquire_link', 0x00000015);
define('enquire_link_resp', 0x80000015);
define('submit_multi', 0x00000021);
define('submit_multi_resp', 0x80000021);
define('alert_notification', 0x00000102);
define('data_sm', 0x00000103);
define('data_sm_resp', 0x80000103);

class SMPPClass
{
// public members:
/*
Constructor.
Parameters:
none.
Example:
$smpp = new SMPPClass();
*/
function SMPPClass()
{
/* seed random generator */
list($usec, $sec) = explode(' ', microtime());
$seed = (float)$sec + ((float)$usec * 100000);
srand($seed);

/* initialize member variables */
$this->_debug = true;
/* set this to false if you want to suppress debug output. */
$this->_socket = null;
$this->_command_status = 0;
$this->_sequence_number = 1;
$this->_source_address = "";
$this->_message_sequence = rand(1, 255);
$this->_message_id = 0;
$this->interface_version = 0x34;
$this->addr_ton = 1;
$this->addr_npi = 1;
$this->address_range = '';
$this->dlvrSms = array();
}

/*
For SMS gateways that support sender-ID branding, the method
can be used to set the originating address.
Parameters:
$from : Originating address
Example:
$smpp->SetSender("31495595392");
*/
function SetSender($from)
{
if (strlen($from) > 20) {
$this->debug("Error: sender id too long.\n");
return;
}
$this->_source_address = $from;
}

/*
This method initiates an SMPP session.
It is to be called BEFORE using the Send() method.
Parameters:
$host : SMPP ip to connect to.
$port : port # to connect to.
$username : SMPP system ID
$password : SMPP passord.
$system_type : SMPP System type
Returns:
true if successful, otherwise false
Example:
$smpp->Start("smpp.chimit.nl", 2345, "chimit", "my_password", "client01");
*/

function getMessageId(){

     return $this->_message_id;
}
function Start($host, $port, $username, $password, $system_type, $type)
{
/*
$testarr = stream_get_transports();
$have_tcp = false;
reset($testarr);
while (list(, $transport) = each($testarr)) {
if ($transport == "tcpp") {
$have_tcp = true;
}
}
if (!$have_tcp) {
$this->debug("No TCP support in this version of PHP.\n");
return false;
}
*/
$this->_socket = @fsockopen($host, $port, $errno, $errstr, 120);
// todo: sanity check on input parameters
if (!$this->_socket) {
$this->debug("Error opening SMPP session.\n");
$this->debug("Error was: $errstr.\n");
return;
}
socket_set_timeout($this->_socket, 120);
//$status = $this->SendBindTransmitter($username, $password, $system_type);

if ($type == 'transmitter') {
$status = $this->SendBindTransmitter($username, $password, $system_type);
} elseif ($type == 'receiver') {
$status = $this->SendBindReceiver($username, $password, $system_type);
}

if ($status != 0) {
$this->debug("Error binding to SMPP server. Invalid credentials?\n");
}
return($status == 0);
}

/*
This method sends out one SMS message.
Parameters:
$to : destination address.
$text : text of message to send.
$unicode: Optional. Indicates if input string is html encoded unicode.
Returns:
true if messages sent successfull, otherwise false.
Example:
$smpp->Send("31649072766", "This is an SMPP Test message.");
$smpp->Send("31648072766", "&#1589;&#1576;&#1575;&#1581;&#1575;&#1604;&#1582;&#1610;&#1585;", true);
*/
function Send($to, $text, $unicode = false)
{
if (strlen($to) > 20) {
$this->debug("to-address too long.\n");
return;
}
if (!$this->_socket) {
$this->debug("Not connected, while trying to send SUBMIT_SM.\n");
// return;
}
$service_type = "";
//default source TON and NPI for international sender
$source_addr_ton = 1;
$source_addr_npi = 1;
$source_addr = $this->_source_address;
if (preg_match('/\D/', $source_addr)) {
//alphanumeric sender
$source_addr_ton = 5;
$source_addr_npi = 0;
} elseif (strlen($source_addr) < 11) {
//national or shortcode sender
$source_addr_ton = 2;
$source_addr_npi = 1;
}
$dest_addr_ton = 1;
$dest_addr_npi = 1;
$destination_addr = $to;
$esm_class = 3;
$protocol_id = 0;
$priority_flag = 0;
$schedule_delivery_time = "";
$validity_period = "";
$registered_delivery_flag = 1;
$replace_if_present_flag = 0;
$data_coding = 241;
$sm_default_msg_id = 0;
if ($unicode) {
$text = mb_convert_encoding($text, "UCS-2BE", "HTML-ENTITIES");
/* UCS-2BE */
$data_coding = 8;
/* UCS2 */
$multi = $this->split_message_unicode($text);
} else {
$multi = $this->split_message($text);
}
$multiple = (count($multi) > 1);
if ($multiple) {
$esm_class += 0x00000040;
}
$result = true;
reset($multi);
while (list(, $part) = each($multi)) {
$short_message = $part;
$sm_length = strlen($short_message);
$status = $this->SendSubmitSM($service_type, $source_addr_ton, $source_addr_npi, $source_addr, $dest_addr_ton, $dest_addr_npi, $destination_addr, $esm_class, $protocol_id, $priority_flag, $schedule_delivery_time, $validity_period, $registered_delivery_flag, $replace_if_present_flag, $data_coding, $sm_default_msg_id, $sm_length, $short_message);
if ($status != 0) {
$this->debug("SMPP server returned error $status.\n");
$result = false;
}
}
return $result;
}

/*
This method ends a SMPP session.
Parameters:
none
Returns:
true if successful, otherwise false
Example: $smpp->End();
*/
function end()
{
if (!$this->_socket) {
// not connected
return;
}
$status = $this->SendUnbind();
if ($status != 0) {
$this->debug("SMPP Server returned error $status.\n");
}
fclose($this->_socket);
$this->_socket = null;
return($status == 0);
}

/*
This method sends an enquire_link PDU to the server and waits for a response.
Parameters:
none
Returns:
true if successfull, otherwise false.
Example: $smpp->TestLink()
*/
function TestLink()
{
$pdu = "";
$status = $this->SendPDU(enquire_link, $pdu);
return($status == 0);
}

function ReadSms()
{
$pdu = "";
$status = true;
$m = 0;
echo date('H:i:s') . "\n";
$status = $this->SendPDU(deliver_sm_resp, $pdu);

return $this->dlvrSms;
}

function QuerySms($message_id, $gsm)
{
$this->dlvrSms = array();
socket_set_timeout($this->_socket, 120);
$pdu = "";

$message_id = $message_id;
$source_addr_ton = 1;
$source_addr_npi = 1;
$source_addr = $gsm;


////$pdu = pack($message_id . chr(0), $source_addr_ton . chr(0), $source_addr_npi . chr(0), $source_addr);
$status = $this->SendPDU(deliver_sm, $pdu);

 ////$this->ExpectPDU(0);
return $this->dlvrSms;
}

/*
This method sends a single message to a comma separated list of phone numbers.
There is no limit to the number of messages to send.
Parameters:
$tolist : comma seperated list of phone numbers
$text : text of message to send
$unicode: Optional. Indicates if input string is html encoded unicode string.
Returns:
true if messages received by smpp server, otherwise false.
Example:
$smpp->SendMulti("31777110204,31649072766,...,...", "This is an SMPP Test message.");
*/
function SendMulti($tolist, $text, $unicode = false)
{
if (!$this->_socket) {
$this->debug("Not connected, while trying to send SUBMIT_MULTI.\n");
// return;
}

$service_type = '';
//default source TON and NPI for international sender
$source_addr_ton = 1;
$source_addr_npi = 1;
$source_addr = $this->_source_address;
if (preg_match('/\D/', $source_addr)) {
//alphanumeric sender
$source_addr_ton = 5;
$source_addr_npi = 0;
} elseif (strlen($source_addr) < 11) {
//national or shortcode sender
$source_addr_ton = 2;
$source_addr_npi = 1;
}
$dest_addr_ton = 1;
$dest_addr_npi = 1;
$destination_arr = explode(",", $tolist);
$esm_class = 3;
$protocol_id = 0;
$priority_flag = 0;
$schedule_delivery_time = "";
$validity_period = "";
$registered_delivery_flag = 1;
$replace_if_present_flag = 0;
$data_coding = 241;
$sm_default_msg_id = 0;
if ($unicode) {
$text = mb_convert_encoding($text, "UCS-2BE", "HTML-ENTITIES");
$data_coding = 8;
/* UCS2 */
$multi = $this->split_message_unicode($text);
} else {
$multi = $this->split_message($text);
}
$multiple = (count($multi) > 1);
if ($multiple) {
$esm_class += 0x00000040;
}
$result = true;
reset($multi);
while (list(, $part) = each($multi)) {
$short_message = $part;
$sm_length = strlen($short_message);
$status = $this->SendSubmitMulti($service_type, $source_addr_ton, $source_addr_npi, $source_addr, $dest_addr_ton, $dest_addr_npi, $destination_arr, $esm_class, $protocol_id, $priority_flag, $schedule_delivery_time, $validity_period, $registered_delivery_flag, $replace_if_present_flag, $data_coding, $sm_default_msg_id, $sm_length, $short_message);
if ($status != 0) {
$this->debug("SMPP server returned error $status.\n");
$result = false;
}
}
return $result;
}

// private members (not documented):

function ExpectPDU($our_sequence_number)
{
do {
$this->debug("\n\nTrying to read PDU.\n");
if (feof($this->_socket)) {
$this->debug("Socket was closed.!!\n");
return false;
}
$elength = fread($this->_socket, 4);

if (empty($elength)) {
$this->debug("Connection lost.\n");
return false;
}
extract(unpack("Nlength", $elength));

$this->debug("Reading PDU : $length bytes.\n");
$stream = fread($this->_socket, $length - 4);
//$stream = fread($this->_socket, 12);
if (!$stream)
return false;

$this->debug("Stream len : " . strlen($stream) . "\n");
$this->debug("Stream Hex : " . $this->printHex($stream) . "\n");
extract(unpack("Ncommand_id/Ncommand_status/Nsequence_number", $stream));


//$info = stream_get_meta_data($this->_socket);

//$this->debug("stream_get_meta_data id : ".var_export($info,true)."\n");


$command_id &= 0x0fffffff;

$this->debug("Command id : $command_id.\n");
$this->debug("Command status : $command_status.\n");
$this->debug("sequence_number : $sequence_number.\n");

$pdu = substr($stream, 12);
//$pdu=$stream;

switch ($command_id) {
case bind_transmitter:
$this->debug("Got bind_transmitter_RESP.\n");
$spec = "asystem_id";
//extract($this->unpack2($spec, $pdu));
$this->debug("system id : $system_id.\n");
break;
case bind_receiver:
$this->debug("Got bind_receiver_RESP.\n");
$spec = "asystem_id";
extract($this->unpack2($spec, $pdu));
$this->debug("system id : $system_id.\n");
break;
case unbind:
$this->debug("Got unbind_RESP.\n");
break;
case submit_sm:
$this->debug("Got submit_sm_RESP.\n");
if ($command_status == 0) {
$spec = "amessage_id";
extract($this->unpack2($spec, $pdu));
$this->debug("message id : $message_id.\n");
$this->_message_id = $message_id;
}
break;
case submit_multi:
$this->debug("Got submit_multi_RESP.\n");
$spec = "amessage_id/cno_unsuccess/";
extract($this->unpack2($spec, $pdu));
$this->debug("message id : $message_id.\n");
$this->debug("no_unsuccess : $no_unsuccess.\n");
break;
case enquire_link:
$this->debug("GOT enquire_link_RESP.\n");
break;
case deliver_sm;
$this->debug("GOT deliver_sm.\n");
$body = substr($stream, 8, $length);
$this->dlvrSms[] = $this->parseSMS($body, $sequence_number);
$this->SendPDU(deliver_sm_resp, "",$sequence_number);
break;
case deliver_sm_resp;
$this->debug("GOT deliver_sm_resp.\n");
//$body = substr($stream,8, $length);
//$this->dlvrSms[]= $this->parseSMS($body);
break;
case query_sm;
$this->debug("GOT deliver_sm.\n");
$body = substr($stream, 8, $length);
$this->dlvrSms[] = $this->parseSMS($body, $sequence_number);
break;
case generic_nack:
$this->debug("Got generic_nack SMPP pdu.\n");
$spec = "ccommand_length/ccommand_id/ccommand_status/csequence_number";
extract($this->unpack2($spec, $pdu));
$this->debug("command_length generic_nack == " . $command_length . "\n");
$this->debug("command_id generic_nack == " . $command_id . "\n");
$this->debug("command_status generic_nack == " . $command_status . "\n");
$this->debug("command_status generic_nack == " . $command_status . "\n");
break;
default:
$this->debug("Got unknow $command_id SMPP pdu.\n");
}

$this->debug("\nReceived PDU: \n");
for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($stream); $i++) {
if (ord($stream[$i]) < 32)
$this->debug("(" . ord($stream[$i]) . ")");
else
$this->debug($stream[$i]);
}
$this->debug("\n");
} while ($sequence_number != $our_sequence_number);
return $command_status;
}

/**
* @private function
* Parse deliver PDU from SMSC.
* @param $pdu - deliver PDU from SMSC.
* @return parsed PDU as array.
*/
function parseSMS($body, $sequence_number)
{
//check command id

//unpack PDU
$ar = unpack("C*", $body);
//$ar=unpack("C*",$pdu['body']);
$sms = array('service_type' => $this->getString($ar, 6), 'source_addr_ton' => array_shift($ar), 'source_addr_npi' => array_shift($ar), 'source_addr' => $this->getString($ar, 21), 'dest_addr_ton' => array_shift($ar), 'dest_addr_npi' => array_shift($ar), 'destination_addr' => $this->getString($ar, 21), 'esm_class' => array_shift($ar), 'protocol_id' => array_shift($ar), 'priority_flag' => array_shift($ar), 'schedule_delivery_time' => array_shift($ar), 'validity_period' => array_shift($ar), 'registered_delivery' => array_shift($ar), 'replace_if_present_flag' => array_shift($ar), 'data_coding' => array_shift($ar), 'sm_default_msg_id' => array_shift($ar), 'sm_length' => array_shift($ar), 'short_message' => $this->getString($ar, 255));

// $this->_sequence_number=$sequence_number;

//send responce of recieving sms

return $sms;
}

function SendPDU($command_id, $pdu, $sequence_number = null)
{
if ($sequence_number == null) {
$sequence_number = $this->_sequence_number;
}

$length = strlen($pdu) + 16;
$header = pack("NNNN", $length, $command_id, $this->_command_status, $sequence_number);
$this->debug("Sending PDU, len == $length\n");
$this->debug("Sending PDU, header-len == " . strlen($header) . "\n");
$this->debug("Sending PDU, command_id == " . $command_id . "\n");
$this->debug("Sending PDU, sequence number == " . $sequence_number . "\n");
$this->debug("Sending PDU, command status == " . $this->_command_status . "\n");

fwrite($this->_socket, $header . $pdu, $length);
$status = $this->ExpectPDU($sequence_number);
$this->_sequence_number = $this->_sequence_number + 1;
return $status;
}

function SendBindTransmitter($system_id, $smpppassword, $system_type)
{
$system_id = $system_id . chr(0);
$system_id_len = strlen($system_id);
$smpppassword = $smpppassword . chr(0);
$smpppassword_len = strlen($smpppassword);
$system_type = $system_type . chr(0);
$system_type_len = strlen($system_type);
$pdu = pack("a{$system_id_len}a{$smpppassword_len}a{$system_type_len}CCCa1", $system_id, $smpppassword, $system_type, $this->interface_version, $this->addr_ton, $this->addr_npi, $this->address_range);
$this->debug("Bind Transmitter PDU: ");
for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($pdu); $i++) {
$this->debug(ord($pdu[$i]) . " ");
}
$this->debug("\n");
$status = $this->SendPDU(bind_transmitter, $pdu);
return $status;
}

function SendBindReceiver($system_id, $smpppassword, $system_type)
{
$system_id = $system_id . chr(0);
$system_id_len = strlen($system_id);
$smpppassword = $smpppassword . chr(0);
$smpppassword_len = strlen($smpppassword);
$system_type = $system_type . chr(0);
$system_type_len = strlen($system_type);
$pdu = pack("a{$system_id_len}a{$smpppassword_len}a{$system_type_len}CCCa1" . (strlen($this->address_range) + 1), $system_id, $smpppassword, $system_type, $this->interface_version, $this->addr_ton, $this->addr_npi, $this->address_range);
$this->debug("Bind Receiver PDU: ");
for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($pdu); $i++) {
$this->debug(ord($pdu[$i]) . " ");
}
$this->debug("\n");
$status = $this->SendPDU(bind_transceiver, $pdu);
return $status;
}


function SendUnbind()
{
$pdu = "";
$status = $this->SendPDU(unbind, $pdu);
return $status;
}

function SendSubmitSM($service_type, $source_addr_ton, $source_addr_npi, $source_addr, $dest_addr_ton, $dest_addr_npi, $destination_addr, $esm_class, $protocol_id, $priority_flag, $schedule_delivery_time, $validity_period, $registered_delivery_flag, $replace_if_present_flag, $data_coding, $sm_default_msg_id, $sm_length, $short_message)
{
$service_type = $service_type . chr(0);
$service_type_len = strlen($service_type);
$source_addr = $source_addr . chr(0);
$source_addr_len = strlen($source_addr);
$destination_addr = $destination_addr . chr(0);
$destination_addr_len = strlen($destination_addr);
$schedule_delivery_time = $schedule_delivery_time . chr(0);
$schedule_delivery_time_len = strlen($schedule_delivery_time);
$validity_period = $validity_period . chr(0);
$validity_period_len = strlen($validity_period);
// $short_message = $short_message . chr(0);
$message_len = $sm_length;
$spec = "a{$service_type_len}cca{$source_addr_len}cca{$destination_addr_len}ccca{$schedule_delivery_time_len}a{$validity_period_len}ccccca{$message_len}";
$this->debug("PDU spec: $spec.\n");

$pdu = pack($spec, $service_type, $source_addr_ton, $source_addr_npi, $source_addr, $dest_addr_ton, $dest_addr_npi, $destination_addr, $esm_class, $protocol_id, $priority_flag, $schedule_delivery_time, $validity_period, $registered_delivery_flag, $replace_if_present_flag, $data_coding, $sm_default_msg_id, $sm_length, $short_message);
$status = $this->SendPDU(submit_sm, $pdu);
return $status;
}

function SendSubmitMulti($service_type, $source_addr_ton, $source_addr_npi, $source_addr, $dest_addr_ton, $dest_addr_npi, $destination_arr, $esm_class, $protocol_id, $priority_flag, $schedule_delivery_time, $validity_period, $registered_delivery_flag, $replace_if_present_flag, $data_coding, $sm_default_msg_id, $sm_length, $short_message)
{
$service_type = $service_type . chr(0);
$service_type_len = strlen($service_type);
$source_addr = $source_addr . chr(0);
$source_addr_len = strlen($source_addr);
$number_destinations = count($destination_arr);
$dest_flag = 1;
$spec = "a{$service_type_len}cca{$source_addr_len}c";
$pdu = pack($spec, $service_type, $source_addr_ton, $source_addr_npi, $source_addr, $number_destinations);

$dest_flag = 1;
reset($destination_arr);
while (list(, $destination_addr) = each($destination_arr)) {
$destination_addr .= chr(0);
$dest_len = strlen($destination_addr);
$spec = "ccca{$dest_len}";
$pdu .= pack($spec, $dest_flag, $dest_addr_ton, $dest_addr_npi, $destination_addr);
}
$schedule_delivery_time = $schedule_delivery_time . chr(0);
$schedule_delivery_time_len = strlen($schedule_delivery_time);
$validity_period = $validity_period . chr(0);
$validity_period_len = strlen($validity_period);
$message_len = $sm_length;
$spec = "ccca{$schedule_delivery_time_len}a{$validity_period_len}ccccca{$message_len}";

$pdu .= pack($spec, $esm_class, $protocol_id, $priority_flag, $schedule_delivery_time, $validity_period, $registered_delivery_flag, $replace_if_present_flag, $data_coding, $sm_default_msg_id, $sm_length, $short_message);

$this->debug("\nMulti PDU: ");
for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($pdu); $i++) {
if (ord($pdu[$i]) < 32)
$this->debug(".");
else
$this->debug($pdu[$i]);
}
$this->debug("\n");

//$this->_command_status='';
$status = $this->SendPDU(submit_multi, $pdu);
return $status;
}




function split_message($text)
{
$this->debug("\n\nIn split_message.\n");
$max_len = 153;
$res = array();
if (strlen($text) <= 160) {
$this->debug("One message: " . strlen($text) . "\n");
$res[] = $text;
return $res;
}
$pos = 0;
$msg_sequence = $this->_message_sequence++;
$num_messages = ceil(strlen($text) / $max_len);
$part_no = 1;
while ($pos < strlen($text)) {
$ttext = substr($text, $pos, $max_len);
$pos += strlen($ttext);
$udh = pack("cccccc", 5, 0, 3, $msg_sequence, $num_messages, $part_no);
$part_no++;
$res[] = $udh . $ttext;
$this->debug("Split: UDH = ");
for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($udh); $i++) {
$this->debug(ord($udh[$i]) . " ");
}
$this->debug("\n");
$this->debug("Split: $ttext.\n");
}
return $res;
}

function split_message_unicode($text)
{
$this->debug("\n\nIn split_message.\n");
$max_len = 134;
$res = array();
if (mb_strlen($text) <= 140) {
$this->debug("One message: " . mb_strlen($text) . "\n");
$res[] = $text;
return $res;
}
$pos = 0;
$msg_sequence = $this->_message_sequence++;
$num_messages = ceil(mb_strlen($text) / $max_len);
$part_no = 1;
while ($pos < mb_strlen($text)) {
$ttext = mb_substr($text, $pos, $max_len);
$pos += mb_strlen($ttext);
$udh = pack("cccccc", 5, 0, 3, $msg_sequence, $num_messages, $part_no);
$part_no++;
$res[] = $udh . $ttext;
$this->debug("Split: UDH = ");
for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($udh); $i++) {
$this->debug(ord($udh[$i]) . " ");
}
$this->debug("\n");
$this->debug("Split: $ttext.\n");
}
return $res;
}

function unpack2($spec, $data)
{
$res = array();
$specs = explode("/", $spec);
$pos = 0;
reset($specs);
while (list(, $sp) = each($specs)) {
$subject = substr($data, $pos);
$type = substr($sp, 0, 1);
$var = substr($sp, 1);
switch ($type) {
case "N":
$temp = unpack("Ntemp2", $subject);
$res[$var] = $temp["temp2"];
$pos += 4;
break;
case "c":
$temp = unpack("ctemp2", $subject);
$res[$var] = $temp["temp2"];
$pos += 1;
break;
case "a":
$pos2 = strpos($subject, chr(0)) + 1;
$temp = unpack("a{$pos2}temp2", $subject);
$res[$var] = $temp["temp2"];
$pos += $pos2;
break;
}
}
return $res;
}

/**
* @private function
* Reads C style zero padded string from the char array.
* @param $ar - input array
* @param $maxlen - maximum length to read.
* @return readed string.
*/
function getString(&$ar, $maxlen = 255)
{
$s = "";
$i = 0;
do {

$c = array_shift($ar);
if ($c != 0)
$s .= chr($c);
$i++;
} while ($i < $maxlen && $c != 0);
return $s;
}

/**
* @private function
* Prints the binary string as hex bytes.
* @param $maxlen - maximum length to read.
*/
function printHex($pdu)
{
$a = "";
$ar = unpack("C*", $pdu);
foreach ($ar as $v) {
$s = dechex($v);
if (strlen($s) < 2)
$s = "0$s";
$a .= "$s ";
}
return $a . "\n";
}

function debug($str)
{
if ($this->_debug) {
echo $str;
}
}
}

?>
```

Deliver_sm and Deliver_sm_resp is not working, When i request for delivery report the server is sending me deliver_sm but deliver_sm_resp is not working.

Any body know how to receive delivery report of specific sms, although i have message id of every sms.

Comment: That is a TON of code, can you pair it down to just the part you have questions about? Also please format the code with proper indentation.

Comment: the problem is in deliver_sm and deliver_sm_resp and also there is a problem in querySMS function packing.